# Unable to create directory in wp-content/uploads in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, permissions, centos

I am not able to upload any images to the Media section.
I get this error message:

> "Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2015/05. Is its parent
> directory writable by the server?"

I tried changing the permissions, gave full access 777 to both uploads, and wp-content directory but this didn't help.

I tried changing the owners to apache : apache for /wordpress/wp-content, but that hasn't helped either.

upload_path is set to wp-content/uploads in option-media.php. Still it is not working.

Tried defining upload path `define(UPLOADS, 'wp-content/uploads');`No Help.

(server: centos)

Comment: check Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders in media in wordpress admin and check  / uncheck vice versa and try to upload images

Comment: Tried, Still not working. Now I get error "The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads."

Answer (score 44):

Debian like:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/{yourpath}/wp-content/uploads
```

Comment: This will only work if you are on a Debian/Ubuntu like distro. For RH/CentOS and the like you'll need to use apache:apache as those are the appropriate accounts. Also, you don't need that on the entire /var/www. That would be an insecure setup. Apache only need write access to places you intend to upload through the website.

Comment: This works fine for me. However the path could vary depending on the installation. In my case it is /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/uploads

Comment: Works like charm on Ubuntu!

Answer (score 14):

I was having a similar problem after migrating from a development site to a production site.  It turned out that the message is deceptive.  Check Settings, Media.  Verify the directory for media is accurate for the current site.  If the site was migrated, the directory listed still be from the old site and may need to be updated.

Comment: Migration was the issue for me and this fixed it, thanks. Error is certainly misleading.

Answer (score 8):

Change permissions on the /wp-content directory to 0775 and try it again.

```
sudo chmod 0775 {yourpath}/wp-content/uploads
```

If it fails, change the permissions to 0777 and try again.

```
sudo chmod 0777 {yourpath}/wp-content/uploads
```

Once it is successful, be sure to return the permissions on /wp-content to whatever they were when you started.

You may also want to put the permissions back on any other files you changed while attempting to resolve the issue.

More options you can find here: https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/how-to-fix-the-unable-to-create-directory-error-in-wordpress-5264

Reggards

Answer (score 7):

If this error is showed after migrating wordpress to new server check upload path in:
settings->media->Store uploads in this folder

default value is wp-content/uploads.

Probably you have old path.

Comment: This answer is relevant as it solves it for me.

Answer (score 6):

You may have to add a folder named uploads first before you change any permissions.

My environment is xampp in Ubuntu 18.04 and the Wordpress installation failed to create the folder 'uploads'.

cd into the wp-content directory.

`mkdir uploads`

while still in the wp-content path, use chmod 0777 to add the relevant permissions:

```
sudo chmod 0777 uploads
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Go to `wp-admin/options.php`
Under `upload_path` replace with exactly `wp-content/uploads` (no quotes, no extra slashes)
That worked for me after I had tried to all other solutions for days.

Answer (score 5):

This is a solution when you are on your local but can be applied also on a server.

Sometimes **if you get a backup from the database** that is on a server and you recover it on your local you will have this problem: "*Unable to create directory...*" even if you have the correct permissions on your folder.
This happens because WP points to a value on *upload_path* on the database.

So go to **wp_options** table.

Search for **upload_path** and check if the path is correct.

If not. (on mac and unix) Go to your upload folder, drag it to the terminal. And use **pwd** command copy the response on **upload_path** on the database.

Hopefully this will help someone.

Answer (score 4):

I tried all the solutions from [How to Fix the Unable to create directory Error in WordPress](https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/how-to-fix-the-unable-to-create-directory-error-in-wordpress-5264)  in my Centos7. But it won't work.

Then I found some useful message in /var/log/audit/audit.log

> type=AVC msg=audit(1495357844.782:604): avc:  denied  { write } for 
>   pid=2721 comm="httpd" name="wp-content" dev="dm-5" ino=1074299184
>   scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
>   tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:etc_runtime_t:s0 tclass=dir
>   type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1495357844.782:604): arch=c000003e syscall=83
>   success=no exit=-13 a0=7fffba9c62c0 a1=1ff a2=8 a3=5 items=0 ppid=1556
>   pid=2721 auid=4294967295 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48
>   egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="httpd"
>   exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)

Check the file infomation : `ls -Z /data/web/wordpress`

Found that SELinux prevented Httpd to access the files. So you can disable the SELinux, or modify the file context: chcon -R --type=httpd_sys_rw_content_t /data/web/wordpress . And it works.

Comment: You are a life saver. Been looking for a solution to this for a week and this was the only thing that worked. Never even heard of SELinux until this post. Moral of the story, never use CentOS for wordpress lol stick to debian.

Answer (score 3):

I have managed to solve this by updating the reference to Settings Media Store uploads folder.

Go to WordPress admin -> Settings -> Media, and update `Store uploads in this folder` option with what is in your `public_html` hosting account.

```
/home/<base_folder_name>/public_html/wp-content/uploads
```

For me the `<base_folder_name>` was different than what was in the hosting account.

Comment: I tried everything for my GoDaddy Hosted account and this was it! this was only needed in my root application; any application in a sub-folder was OK.

Answer (score 3):

To solve this annoying error, you need to change the path of the old uploads folder to the new one. Follow these steps to solve the problem:

Log in to your WordPress admin panel (wp-admin).
In the left menu go to Settings » Media.
Media Settings - WordPress
In the Store uploads in this folder field, enter wp-content/uploads and click Save changes.
Change WordPress Uploads Folder
Now you are done, go and try to upload files to the media library again.
NOTE: make sure that the Store uploads in this folder field container image description here wp-content/uploads only.

[image: Follow this image for right direction]

[image]

Another Way:-

If you can’t find the field on your media settings page you can solve the problem by adding the following code in your wp-config.php file:

Go to wp-config file........ using FTP or Local server paste the following code

define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/uploads' );
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');

And the “Unable to Create Directory wp-content/uploads. Is Its Parent Directory Writable by the Server” error will be fixed.

Comment: This one worked for me. Followed your screenshots. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

"The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2015/05."

This error comes because of insufficient permission to your user on to the server.

One Quick and dirty way to solve this error is to set 777 permission but some time it may not also work.

Follow this link this will help you
http://2surge.com/how-to-fix-the-uploaded-file-could-not-be-moved-to-wp-content-error-message/

Thanks

Comment: Tried giving  recursive permission, didnt work.

Created the folder manually, still the same. Only the error message changed.

Comment: Now the error is "The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2015/05."

Comment: feels like there is some server configuration error do you have shell access to your site ?

Comment: editing my ans try with that solution and let me know if that helps you

Answer (score 1):

Try following. Make sure {yourpath} is replaced with correct path

Creates upload directory with super user permission

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/{yourpath}/wp-content/uploads
```

Change ownership to the current user

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/{yourpath}/wp-content/uploads
```

Answer (score 1):

This is sometimes an issue with file and directory ownership than permissions. Find out the user the php code is executing as using `phpinfo()` page.

Once you know the system user, make sure the FTP account you are using is configured to upload the files as that user. If it has been uploaded using different user, use `chown` to change the ownership of the base path to match the user.

For example:

```
$ sudo chown -R <user> /path/to/public_html
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem here on a Parallels Plesk server. I had to change the access permissions for the webserver/website user using the access options from within the file manager.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /path-to-mywordpress-root-folde
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a MAC/ OSX solution and found this related question but it didn't help. The following works for me:
1- Right-click on `wp-content` and go to Get Info and change permissions as follow:

[image: Changing permission for wp-content folder]

After click on the setting gear icon and **Apply to enclosed items...**.

[image: Apply to selected items]

Answer (score 1):

I'm an Arch Linux user. My WordPress location is (/srv/http/wordpress).
I faced this problem before.

At first, I change my WordPress ownerships to $USER:http.

```
sudo chown -R -c $USER:http /srv/http/wordpress
```

(don't go root to change ownership with this command then $USER will be root)

you can check who is the user with

```
echo $USER
```

I created an uploads folder in wordpress/wp-content/uploads.
Then give the read, write, and execute permission to the user and group of wp-content and wp-content/uploads directory.

```
sudo chmod 774 wp-content/
sudo chmod 774 wp-content/uploads/
```

hope it will helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Just run this command:

```
sudo chown -R www-data /path/to/wordpress
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For manjaro Linux in the wordpress directory:

```
sudo chown -R  http:http wp-content
```

That worked for me.

Comment: You should perhaps ask him first to check what user and group the directory is with something like `ls ll` and what user and group Apache uses on his CentOS server using: `egrep -i '^user|^group' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf ` as suggested at https://serverfault.com/questions/416236/what-is-centos-5s-apache-user-group .  Then you can change user and group rights when need be . NB `stat -c "%a %n" *` helps checking chmod rights in numbers.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a disk space issue - my account was simply over its quota and therefore would not allow any increase in the form of a folder creation or plugin installation.

Simply clear some disk space and try again.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had migrated to another server and my media settings had got clobbered. I had to explicitly reset the uploads folder.

Here's what worked for me :

From your Wordpress dashboard go to `Settings->Media` and set

`"Store uploads in this folder"` to `"wp-content/uploads"`

Answer (score 0):

these problem maybe you have faced after changed your hosting just log in your wordpress and and go to Media just change path wp-content.

you can check in deep:- https://blog.aaaenos.com/unable-to-create-directory-uploads-year-month-is-its-parent-directory-writable-by-the-server/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31698509)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the “Is its parent directory writable by the server?” issue occurs because WordPress can’t recognize the location of the uploads folder.

You might face the problem after you have just moved your site to another hosting provider. To fix it, you need to modify your WordPress config file:

1. Access your hosting file manager or FTP, and search for the wp-config.php file. It is commonly located in the root folder of your website (/public_html).
2. Open the file and add the following code:

**define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/uploads' );**

before this line:

**require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');**

3. Save the file. Now, try to upload your media files again.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do `chmod ug+w wp-content/uploads`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error which required me around two dasy and 4 hours to find a solution ( occasionally by the way).
That was a **local** wordpress **installation** on my Fedora 37 (linux distro) running by the LAMPP.
The project was located in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/fu** folder.
The first day I tried everything from creating the "uploads" directory manually to applying the chmod and chown to the wp-content and all folders and files within it. Nothing helped.
The second day I apllied the following commands to the whole /fu/ poject folder

```
find /opt/lampp/htdocs/fu/ -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find /opt/lampp/htdocs/fu/ -type f -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

and the problem has gone.

Comment: Permissions should be as restricted as possible. Files should not be executable.